# Order 1,2,10,11 instead 1,10,11,2

Tags: c#, .net

I have files in my folder with names like these:

```
"C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\333\\12.html"
```

How to sort them so that 2.html will come before 10.html?

Comment: Windows Explorer? Norton Commander? `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`?

Comment: Click the explorer column "Name" to inverse the sorting!

Comment: what does this have to do with c#?

Comment: @CodeCaster I need to do this in C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [Natural Sort Order in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Get the files in a list by using DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() and then sort them on the basis of their name. Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles.aspx

Comment: Try the [link](http://www.naturalordersort.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse the strings as numbers when you sort the files.

Example:

```
string[] files = {
  "2.html",
  "10.html",
  "1.html"
};

files =
  files.OrderBy(s => Int32.Parse(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('.'))))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: And then it will fail on "Part 1.html", "a.html" and "b.html". Your solution will only work in the specific case of file names looking like `<number>.<extension>`.

Comment: @penartur : conform the specs. Read the question.

Comment: The question says "file names are **like** `3.html`", not "file names are exactly `<number>.<extension>`". In the context of question, `part 3.html` is like `3.html`.

Comment: @penartur: The example shows what kind of strings it works with. Whatever anyone may think about what the question means, the answer in itself defines what question it is answering.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Directory
      .GetFiles()
      .OrderBy(f => int.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this post -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11016/Numeric-String-Sort-in-C

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles();

NumericComparer ns = new NumericComparer();
Array.Sort(files, ns);

// files will now sorted in the numeric order
// we can do the same for directories

string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories();
ns = new NumericComparer(); // new object
Array.Sort(dirs, ns);

public class NumericComparer : IComparer
    {
        public NumericComparer()
        {}

        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            if((x is string) && (y is string))
            {
                return StringLogicalComparer.Compare((string)x, (string)y);
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }//EOC
```

Comment: In what anmespace is NumericComparer ?

Comment: @user1322207 Look at the link there is a source example to download, I also edit my answer